# Why don't I have an animation control bar in fireworks cs4 on the mac?

Tags: user-interface, adobe-fireworks

following along with the Lynda.com tutorial, and it demonstrates using a little animation control bar at the base of the doument window, but mine is not there!!

I can't find the setting to turn it on, or any other info. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer was that the window was overlapping other elements by default. Silly Adobe, well done expose!!